# How to return the rows that has only one max date for duplicate row_num

Tags: sql

I have a table with schema like this:

```
row_num, row_id, event_date
```

The `row_id` is unique, but `row_num` can be duplicated.

How to write a SQL query that will return rows, for the `row_num` which has exactly one max `event_date`?

Sample data looks like this:

```
 { rownum: 20, row_id: 1, event_date: '2019-10-10' }
 { rownum: 20, row_id: 2, event_date: '2019-10-10' }
 { rownum: 21, row_id: 3, event_date: '2018-10-12' }
 { rownum: 21, row_id: 4, event_date: '2020-09-09' }
 { rownum: 22, row_id: 5, event_date: null }
 { rownum: 22, row_id: 6, event_date: '2019-10-11' }
```

So the above should return row_id = 4 and 6 and how to return the rows that not with max event date for that same row number.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Do you just need the row_id values, or the other values too? *(Just the two values, or the four rows associates with those values?)*

Comment: @MatBailie I just need row_ids for that row_num that has just one max date

Comment: You still haven't cleared up what database product you are actually using?

Comment: Please read "How to ask", and the chapter in it with the name: [Respond to feedback after posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Respond%20to%20feedback%20after%20posting)

Answer (score 1):

Use `RANK()` to identify the rows associated with the max date (per row_num). Then use `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause to get only the row_nums with exactly one such row (MAX date). Finally, `MAX()` will pick out that row's `row_id`.

```
WITH
  ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    row_id,
    row_num,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY row_num
          ORDER BY event_date DESC
    )
       AS row_num_rank
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  MAX(row_id) AS row_id
FROM
  ranked
WHERE
  row_num_rank = 1
GROUP BY
  row_num
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```

Or, just use two window functions...

```
WITH
  ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    row_id,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY row_num
          ORDER BY event_date DESC
    )
       AS row_num_rank,
    COUNT(*) OVER (
      PARTITION BY row_num,
                   event_date
    )
       AS row_num_date_count
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  row_id
FROM
  ranked
WHERE
      row_num_rank       = 1
  AND row_num_date_count = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not returning correct expected output, for example: [
{row_num:20, row_id:1, event_date: '2020'},
{row_num:20, row_id:2, event_date: '2020'},
{row_num:20, row_id:3, event_date: '2019}
]:
it should not return row_id for row_num = 20

Comment: @itachi_16 Not sure what you ran (there was a typo in the first query), but it seems to work for me; https://dbfiddle.uk/pBX3jtUE

Comment: Without knowing the platform we can't be sure how those null dates are going to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Get the rows where there isn't another one with a later or equal date. Nulls are treated as a convenient dummy date that would never appear in the data. This should be portable across a lot of platforms.

```
select * from T t1 where not exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where   t2.row_num = t1.row_num
        and t2.row_id <> t1.row_id
        and coalesce(t2.event_date, '2000-01-01')
         >= coalesce(t1.event_date, '2000-01-01')
);
```

You could use `t2.event_date is distinct from t1.event_date` to get index support and a cleaner query in many newer platforms.

Comment: Except for the typo in the query, this looks good. +1

Comment: Always hard to type and edit code on this phone keyboard!

Comment: That pair of COALESCE expressions is unfortunately going to obfuscate any indexes present.

Comment: Maybe so. If we knew what platform we're on we might worry at that point. Seems like the first column is most important anyway. And the other answer assumes ids are always in ascending order.

Comment: Not sure this issue raised my @MatBailie is a matter of knowing what DBMS is being used. IMO, it comes down to what to do with null `event_date`s when there is no other record with the same `row_id` and it should be possible to solve it with ANSI SQL only. If `NULL` values must be returned when they are by themselves, then simply change that "`coalesce`" part for (I think but I have not thoroughly tested) `((t1.event_date is NULL AND t2.event_date IS NOT NULL) OR t2.event_date >= t1.event_date)`. If not, add `t1.event_date IS NOT NULL AND` before the `not exists`. No?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that nulls in indexes are treated differently on some platforms, Oracle being one. In fact I used to work on a DB2 system where the DBAs had us specifically use a dummy `coalesce()` so that it *would* pick those indexes.

Comment: I see... then maybe offer several versions of the query to satisfy everyone, with the instruction that OP should check the execution plan and keep the query that executes best on their DBMS. Honestly, I think that would make the answer more valuable like this than if it was specifically written for a specific DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use analytic functions to get max, count distinct and count of event dates per ROW_NUM first. Then count ROW_IDs with max event date and filter the result to those that count just 1:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (ROW_NUM, ROW_ID, EVENT_DATE) AS
        ( Select 20, 1, To_Date('2019-10-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
          Select 20, 2, To_Date('2019-10-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
          Select 21, 3, To_Date('2018-10-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
          Select 21, 4, To_Date('2020-09-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
          Select 22, 5, null From Dual Union All
          Select 22, 6, To_Date('2019-10-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT ROW_ID
FROM   (  Select ROW_ID, 
                 Count(Case When EVENT_DATE = MAX_DATE Then ROW_ID End) OVER(Partition By ROW_NUM) "CNT_MAX"
          From   ( Select  t.*, 
                           Max(T.EVENT_DATE) Over(Partition By ROW_NUM) "MAX_DATE"
                   From tbl t
                 )
          Where EVENT_DATE = MAX_DATE 
      )
WHERE CNT_MAX = 1
```

```sql
/*
    ROW_ID
----------
         4
         6  */
```

Comment: Count distinct is always less than or equal to count. Neither counts nulls. We don't know for sure about "duplicate" nulls in the data, but a max of null would fail the equality tests as well.

Comment: @shawnt00 Count distinct and count was a leftover from version before, thanks, I removed it. Max of null will not fail - if there is just one row_num with null date it will not be selected because that row_num has no date at all meaning no max date so it should not be selected. If there is any row with the date along with null date then there will be max date for that row_num.

Comment: As noted it's unclear whether there can be a duplicate max null.

Comment: @shawnt00 There can be 6 rows of same row_num, lets say 23, and all have null date -nothing will fail. Those rows will simply be "out of game" cause they have no max date at all. Try it and see yourself. And if just one of them has a date that will be max date for the row_num 23.

Comment: Right. When this question was posted there was a lot of contradictory information to sort through and I flipped that around again. I think OP may want those nulls. And also `count(distinct)` analytic isn't universal just btw.

Comment: The `CASE` expression inside the `COUNT()` analytic function is redundant. The analytic function is only applied *after* the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Most dialects require sub-queries to be aliased.